# Jquery Clickable audio slider, messes up on window width change

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

I have a custom audio player for a website I'm working on. Its progress bar was made clickable (that is it skips to a certain part of the song, depending on where the prog. bar is clicked.

The slider is by default 1000px, and when vw goes below 1000px, the player becomes 100% of the vw. 
Now here is where the problem starts because as the width decreases, the current time gets off the desired point dramatically (to the right side, read beginning of the song).

I have made a failed attempt at working the function with vw, and currenty am out of ideas completely.
Here's the code for the player, it's a part of the entire play function, but only those parts go for the progress bar:

```
   audio.ontimeupdate = function () {
          $('.progress').css("width", audio.currentTime / audio.duration * 100 + '%');
    }

        $('#slider').bind('click', function (ev) {
            var $div = $(ev.target);
            var $display = $div.find('#progcont');
            var vW = $(window).width();
            var offset = $div.offset();
            var x = ev.clientX - offset.left;

                $('.progress').css("width", x);
               if (vW > 1000){ 
                /*THIS WORKS BUT ONLY TO vW > 1000*/
            audio.currentTime = (x / 850 * audio.duration);
               } else{
            /*FAILED ATTEMPT BELOW*/
            audio.currentTime = ((x / (vW / 1.7)) * audio.duration) ;

               }
        });
```

Really grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by making the script take not pixel value, but the percentage:

```
        $('#slider').bind('click', function (ev) {  

            var $div = $(ev.target);
            var $display = $div.find('#progcont');
            var vW = $(window).width();  
            var pW = $("#progcont").width();
            var offset = $div.offset();
            var x = ev.clientX - offset.left;  
            var ProcRatio = x / pW;

                   audio.currentTime = ProcRatio * audio.duration;

        });
```